# Folder not synchronizing with Git and Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, git, git-cvs

I am using Eclipse with git remote repositories.

For some reason, there is a folder (and all the subfolders) that are not synchronizing with the remote repository. Modified files inside those folders don't appear with the asterisk (*), and for that reason, they cannot be staged nor committed.

When I enter in www.bitbucket.org to see my project, what I get in that folder is just the icon with the blue arrow next to the name of my "no-folder" and not the regular folder icon, which is the one that appears next to the folders that can be reached and synchronize well.

[image: blue arrow icon next to "false folders"]
[image: regular folder icon next to folders that are synchronized and work well]

Options --> Team --> Add To Index is not working. `git add <folder>` neither

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Pedro

Here you have the git status dump:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   .project
#   modified:   app/AppKernel.php
#   modified:   app/bootstrap.php.cache
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-DemoBundle-Controller-DemoController    #contactAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-DemoBundle-Controller-DemoController    #helloAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-DemoBundle-Controller-DemoController    #indexAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-DemoBundle-Controller-DemoController.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Xtremapp-DemoBundle-Controller-SecuredController    #loginAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Xtremapp-DemoBundle-Controller-SecuredController    #logoutAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Xtremapp-DemoBundle-Controller-SecuredController    #securityCheckAction.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Xtremapp-DemoBundle-Controller-SecuredController.cache.php
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/annotations/Xtremapp-DemoBundle-Controller-WelcomeController    #indexAction.cache.php
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.meta
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerCompiler.log
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appdevUrlGenerator.php
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appdevUrlGenerator.php.meta
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appdevUrlMatcher.php
#   modified:   app/cache/dev/appdevUrlMatcher.php.meta
#   deleted:    app/cache/dev/assetic/config/0/064cba00a41b006ad8ca939936416158.php
#   modified:   app/config/config.yml
#   modified:   app/config/config_dev.yml
#   modified:   app/config/routing.yml
#   modified:   app/config/routing_dev.yml
#   modified:   app/config/security.yml
#   modified:   deps
#   modified:   src/Acme/StoreBundle/Controller/ConfigurationController.php
#   modified:   src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/translations/messages.es.yml
#   modified:   src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig
#   modified:   vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   vendor/doctrine (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   vendor/symfony (modified content)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   .settings/
#   app/AcmeStoreBundle.php
#   app/Common/
#   app/Resources/
#   app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-StoreBundle-Controller-ConfigurationController    #confAction.cache.php
#   app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-StoreBundle-Controller-ConfigurationController    #configurationAction.cache.php
#   app/cache/dev/annotations/Acme-StoreBundle-Controller-ConfigurationController    #saveConfigurationAction.cache.php
#   app/cache/dev/twig/98/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/99/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/9b/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/a0/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/a4/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ac/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ae/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/b0/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/b3/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/b9/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/bb/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/bc/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/bd/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c0/3a/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c0/89/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c2/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c5/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c6/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c8/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/c9/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ca/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ce/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/e4/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ec/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ee/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/ef/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/f0/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/f3/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/f4/
#   app/cache/dev/twig/f6/
#   app/logs/
#   src/Acme/StoreBundle/.DS_Store
#   src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/.DS_Store
#   src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/views/Configuration/
#   web/bundles/fosjsrouting
```

Re-edit with the .gitignorer of one of the folders I want to be included and are not.
    phpunit.xml
    Tests/autoload.php
    nbproject
    catalog.xml
    Propel/om/*
    Propel/map/*

```
!vendor/vendors.php
!vendor/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the folder/subfolders/files to your repository?

Right-Click on folder->Team->Add to Index

Comment: Actually, yes, o have. But seems like eclipse does nothing with that option. No confirmation message nor action nor changes. Which would be the command to try it from the terminal?

Comment: No... so estrange everything... I have tried with git add folder name. It apparently does it as it does not give any error. But then, when I go back to the eclipse and remote git repository, it still doesn`t synchronize. Sort of lost here :/

Comment: Can you post the output of  `git status`  ?

Comment: There I posted editing the original post. Note that I removed many many lines all to do with cache folders in order the text to fit in the post. I think that my git is really messed up! All cache folders are included (what doesn't make sense at all). And the, as I demand other important folders are missing from the repository. No git add folder worked for me :( any other help?

Comment: what are the contents of .gitignore?

Comment: what I posted is what I get in the dump. I am sorry for being such an ignorant with Git. I am getting too many .gitignore files. Is it supposed that I have to touch each single of them to get each folder added to the repository? I re-edited again with the .gitignore contained one of the folders that I want to be included and it is not